# Smallest subfield containing F and {a}

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let F be a field a E be an it's extension field, let a belongs to E then we define F(a) to be the smallest subfield of E containg both F and {a}. My question here is that, from collection of all the subfields of E containg both F and {a}, How can we choose a smallest one?[because( according to me), we can only compare two sets if either of them is contained in other]

Comment: In this case, $F(a)$ is the *intersection* of all subfields of $E$ containing $F$ and $a$.

Comment: It is not the smallest *set* containing $F$ and $a$, but the smallest *field*.

Comment: You show that there exists a sub-field $G \subset E$ such that every sub-field $H\subset E$ such that $F\cup \{a\}\subset H$ also satisfies $H\supset G.$ ....  When we say that a non-empty family $B$ of sets has a smallest member $c,$ we mean that  $c$ is a subset of every member of $B.$

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed only compare two fields if one of them is contained in the other. In fact, there is a subfield of $E$ that is the *smallest* subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $a$ in the sense that it is indeed contained in every other subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $a$.

You can actually construct it by taking the *intersection* of all subfields of $E$ containing $F$ and $a$. This obviously is contained in all those subfields and it obviously contains $F$ and $a$; the point to verify is that it is a field.